# how to sort from lowest to largest in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have this number array

```
 A= [1  2   3   4
1   2   3   1
3   1   1   2
1   2   1   1
2   1   0   6
1   2   1   0]
```

i want to sort the 4th column from smallest to largest, and the corresponding rows will followed in their new position, something like this:

```
A =[1   2   1   0
1   2   3   1
1   2   1   1
3   1   1   2
1   2   3   4
2   1   0   6]
```

so the last row, become on the top because zero in the 4th column is the smallest number in 4th column, so how i will do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
sortrows(A,columnNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
[~,order] = sort(A(:,4));
A = A(order,:);
```

Comment: i tried it but it give an error: Indexing cannot yield multiple results.

Comment: @nobel: The code is correct, I don't know what's wrong in your case. Maybe you have a variable `sort` shadowing the function `sort`